# ArrayAdapter in android to create simple listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I tried to create an `Activity` in Android, This Activity only contains a `ListView` nothing else.

As I know to fill the listview we need to use an `ArrayAdapter`.

So to understand the ArrayAdapter I have read the following link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

But still I am unable to understand it clearly!

One of the biggest doubt is why the constructor needs a `TextView` resource id while my activity is not having any TextViews what I should have to give it?

I am not saying that this is the only constructor, just that I'm unable to understand the logic behind it.

In order to create a simple listview I also referred to the following link:

[Simple ListView using ArrayAdapter example.](http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90)

But again my main doubt is why it does it need a TextView resource id?

If anybody can explain it with an example it will be very helpful.

**EDIT:**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

ArrayAdapter uses a TextView to display each item within it. Behind the scenes, it uses the `toString()` method of each object that it holds and displays this within the TextView. [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) has a number of constructors that can be used and the one that you have used in your example is:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
```

By default, ArrayAdapter uses the default TextView to display each item. But if you want, you could create your own TextView and implement any complex design you'd like by extending the TextView class. This would then have to go into the layout for your use. You could reference this in the textViewResourceId field to bind the objects to this view instead of the default.

For your use, I would suggest that you use the constructor:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects).
```

In your case, this would be:

```
ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values)
```

and it should be fine. This will bind each string to the default TextView display - plain and simple white background.

So to answer your question, you do not have to use the textViewResourceId.

Comment: so what i understood from your answer is we needed to provide TextView resource id if we are making some complex TextView or custom TextView otherwise we don't need it or we can use default that is provided in android.R.id.text1. Am i right?

Comment: Exactly. You don't need it unless you are trying to create your own views.

Comment: Could I use ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item1) ? because in my case, I want to use HashMap but there is no suitable constructor method that accept hashmap.

Comment: ArrayAdapter makes use of a generic argument which can be anything but you still need a collection to back the adapter. Since in your case, you want to use HashMap, you will have to build your custom adapter from BaseAdapter

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView gave you a detail explanation

Answer (score 22):

> But again main doubt why TextView resource id it needs?

Look at the constructor and the params.

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
```

> Added in API level 1 Constructor
>
> Parameters
>
> `context` The current context.
>
> `resource`    The resource ID for a
>   layout file containing a layout to use when instantiating views.
>
> `textViewResourceId`  The id of the TextView within the layout resource
>   to be populated objects   The objects to represent in the `ListView`.

`android.R.id.text1` refers to the id of text in android resource. So you need not have the one in your activity.

Here's the full list

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

`this` refers to activity context

`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` simple_list_item_1 is the layout in android.R.layout.

`android.R.id.text1` refers to the android resource id.

`values` is a string array from the link you provided

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html

Comment: can you tell me what is the need of int textViewResourceId?

Comment: you want the string to be displayed. so you need a textview. The adapter uses the textview id in the android resource package. You can also use a different constructor of arrayadapter or you can have your own custom adapter

Answer (score 4):

The TextView resource id it needs is for a TextView layout file, so it won't be in the same activity.

You can create it by going to File > New > XML > XML Layout File, and enter the widget type, which is 'TextView' in the root tag field.

Source: https://www.kompulsa.com/the-simplest-way-to-implement-an-android-listview/

Answer (score 3):

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
```

Here, resource means the 'id' of the Layout you are using while instantiating the view.

Now, this layout has many child views with their own ids. So, `textViewResourceId` tells which child view we need to populate with the data.

Answer (score 2):

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
```

I am also new to Android , so i might be wrong. But as per my understanding
while using this for listview creation 2nd argument is the layout of list items.
A layout consists of many views (image view,text view etc). With 3rd argument you are specifying in which view or textview you want the text to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use id for textview. You can learn more from [android arrayadapter](http://techlovejump.com/android-arrayadapter-example-listview/). The below code initializes the arrayadapter.

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.single_item, eatables);
```

Answer (score 1):

For your question answer is `android.R.id.text1` is int: The id of the TextView within the layout resource to be populated.

ArrayAdapter has so many constructors with different number of arguments 
I'm mention some of them

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

Now you can understand each and every constructor is different and they used different list of arguments.

And simple answer is you can use ArrayAdapter with text view inside a target xml file or without. It is doesn't matter. And you not need specify text view id you can use it without. But you may need to go with some advance option with your simple list view you must go with a text view.!

Here sample example

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.ListView,StringArray);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is also a valid code you can use with much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one view in the layout file `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` then you'll have to pass the third argument `android.R.id.text1` to specify the view that should be filled with the array elements (values). But if you have just one view in your layout file, there is no need to specify the third argument.