# Implementing text color-coding in Android Listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, text-coloring

I'm trying to implement color highlighting for specific words in a ListView.

I saw another post here suggesting to embed HTML within the text, as follows:

```
<font color='#FF0000'>Sample text</font>
```

However, this isn't working, and is instead showing up literally (as opposed to the tags taking effect and coloring the text).

I'm assuming there might be some flag I could toggle on that would allow embedded tags, but I have no idea where to start looking, or if this is even the right way to go about color-coding my listview text.

More information:

- Listview in question is a simple 1 item per line listview.
- Listview is populated with data from an array of strings.

My adapter is as follows:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
        android.R.id.text1, 
        screenCode);
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To geht full control over the generated view per item you could override the method [ArrayAdapter.getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)). There you could for example build a TextView which renders the html-formatted Text.

Another solution would be to define your own layout. For details see this question: [ArrayAdapter in android to create simple listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079400/arrayadapter-in-android-to-create-simple-listview?rq=1)