# Using Android Volley, how do I get my JSON Array to show in my ListView?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have created a ListView in my Android App and I am trying to display my JSON Array in it from my server, using Volley. I know the listview is set up correctly because when I create the volley request like below it displays correctly in the ListView (I have set `phoneNoofUser="0123456789"` in my PHP so there is no posting of variables from the Android side):

**This displays correctly in ListView :**

```
// Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(SelectUserReviews_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Review review = new Review();
                                review.setCategory(obj.getString("category"));
                                review.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                review.setPhone(obj.getString("phone"));
                                review.setComment(obj.getString("comment"));

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                reviewList.add(review);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }
```

But when I post `phoneNoofUser` from my app (need to do this because in reality it will not always be `0123456789`) nothing shows up in my app. However, the JSON array response comes up correctly in Toast. Can you tell me how I can fix the problem?

**ListView is not showing each JSON object in ListView, but JSON array response comes up correctly in Toast :**

```
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SelectUserReviews_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        //toast comes up with the correct JSON array response
                        //but can't get the JSON array to come up in my ListView
                        Toast.makeText(PopulistoListView.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(SelectUserReviews_URL,

                                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                                        hidePDialog();

                                        // Parsing json
                                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                            try {


                                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                                Review review = new Review();
                                                review.setCategory(obj.getString("category"));

                                                review.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                                review.setPhone(obj.getString("phone"));
                                                review.setComment(obj.getString("comment"));

                                                reviewList.add(review);

                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }

                                        }

                                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                                    }

                                },
                                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error getting user: " + error.getMessage());
                                        hidePDialog();

                                    }

                                }) {


                        };

                        // Adding request for getting user info to request queue
                        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error getting user: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        })

        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_PHONENUMBER_USER, phoneNoofUser);
                return params;

            }

        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: check you arraylist size

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079400/arrayadapter-in-android-to-create-simple-listview

Comment: @jaikhambhayta when my arraylist is populated reviewList.size gives me 8 results which is correct, when my Listview is empty reviewList.size is 0.

Comment: ok than set your listview.setAdapter(adapter)

Comment: @jaikhambhayta It is set. In `onCreate` : 

`adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, reviewList);`
       `listView.setAdapter(adapter);`
The problem is with how response is called, I believe, not with how adapter or list is set up.

Comment: discribe the baseaspater

Comment: the actully problem with your response \

Comment: when send another number response might be differ so check your response both time when you add correct number and differ than you will know all

Comment: @jaikhambhayta First response is of the form `[{....},{....} etc ]` which is correct, then I added a toast after `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in the second response and I get `[]`

Comment: i think your data are not come correctly

Comment: check the respose post it

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem - displaying my Json objects in a listview - another way. I was already getting a string response in my php file with the `stringrequest` volley call. So on that response I converted the string to a json array, and then the json array into individual objects, and then displayed those in the ListView.

Here's the code I used :

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SelectUserReviews_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //hide the 'loading' box
                        hidePDialog();

                        Toast.makeText(PopulistoListView.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                        JSONArray responseObject = new JSONArray(response);
                            JSONObject obj = responseObject.getJSONObject(i);
                            Review review = new Review();
                            review.setCategory(obj.getString("category"));
                            review.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                            review.setPhone(obj.getString("phone"));
                            review.setComment(obj.getString("comment"));
                           // Toast.makeText(PopulistoListView.this, responseObject.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            reviewList.add(review);

                    }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
                            // Do something to recover ... or kill the app.
                        }
                    }
                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                       // System.out.println("size of reviewlist " + reviewList.size());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(PopulistoListView.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_PHONENUMBER_USER, phoneNoofUser);
                return params;

            }

        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }
```

Comment: Or you could use e.g. Gson and convert your whole response to a list with a oneliner...