# Displaying values in an ArrayList using ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am attempting to create a ListView to display values entered  via an EditText. I am using an `ArrayList` and `ArrayAdapter` but I am afraid I don't fully understand how they work.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.listView1, num1);
```

I am unsure why I am unable to use `android.R.id.listView1` where listView1 is the `id` of my list view in the activity. Is this not the resourceid that the adapter needs to list off my ArrayList?

Below is my full method and delcarations. Sorry if I am being vague in my questions, I don't fully know which terminology to use for what and I don't intend to cause confusion.

```
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> allScores = new ArrayList<>();
ListView listScores = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

public void onButtonClick(View V){
    EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scorePrompt);
    TextView output1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTotal);
    String blankCheck = input1.getText().toString(); //CHANGE INPUT IN scorePrompt TO STRING

    TextView output2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custName); //TEST FOR ARRAY LIST DISPLAY
    if (blankCheck.equals("")) {
        Toast blankError = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YOU CANT SKIP HOLES JERK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        blankError.show();
    } else {
        //savedScores.add(input1.getText().toString());//Save input into array list
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText().toString()); //Get input from text box
        int sum = num1 + score2;
        score2 = sum;

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.listView1, num1);

        output1.setText("Your score is : " + Integer.toString(sum));
        input1.setText(""); //Clear input text box

    }
};
```

For some background information on my intentions, I want the user to enter integers in an EditText, save these values in an ArrayList, and then populate a ListView line-by-line with the values the user entered. Thank you for the help.

Comment: It might help you...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079400/arrayadapter-in-android-to-create-simple-listview

Answer (score 0):

Try This way.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

here you have to use setadapter of listview not put in the adapter

try this

```
  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,allscores);
  listscores.setAdapter(adapter)
```

if you want to add input things than make an Arraylist and simply pass it in adapter's third parameter

Comment: Thank you! This seemed to work, but now I am encountering another problem. My app instantly crashes when started. I parsed through the code and found that it occurs when I am creating my "ListView". I am not sure why this is.

Comment: Hey Jigar. I actually was able to find a solution to my problem. I was unaware that I had to initialize my `ArrayList` inside of my onCreate method. I am going to mess around with this and hopefully get it to work. Thank you for everything!