# ListView text/Button code issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a listview on an activity that contains pressable buttons that will display an image. However, I'm running into problems creating a plain list view of just text. My code compiles correctly, but when ran on the phone, it crashes when I click to open up the activity. Am I missing something important in my code, or did I forget to add something somewhere else?

```
public class druglist extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] fulldruglist = {"Aspirin","Acetaminophen","Activated Charcoal","Adenosine",
        "Afrin","Albuterol","Amiodarone","Aspirin"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_druglist);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.activity_druglist, fulldruglist);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.druglistview);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

Comment: Please post your logcat log here. Also - per convention - class names should be in UpperCamelCase (druglist -> DrugList), non-final variables should be in lowerCamelCase (fulldruglist -> fullDrugList).

Answer (score 0):

Here lies your issue:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.activity_druglist, fulldruglist);
```

here the layout you need to provide is the layout used for the item.
but 2 lines above you have :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_druglist);
```

saying that the layout you provide is the layout used for the container

let's assume that you defined your list in layout `R.layout.activity_druglist` and that you defined the layout of each entry of your list in layout `R.layout.activity_druglist_item`, you should write:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.activity_druglist_item, fulldruglist);
```

---

**Update**: Here is some minimalistic code to display your listview :

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView myListView;

    String[] fulldruglist = {"Aspirin","Acetaminophen","Activated Charcoal",
        "Adenosine", "Afrin","Albuterol","Amiodarone","Aspirin"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myListView = findViewById(R.id.myListView);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item,
            R.id.textView, fulldruglist);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**item.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Text" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`activity_main` is the layout of the activity containing the listview

`item` is the layout of the cell's content

`textView` is the `TextView` that will be used to display each entry of your `fulldruglist`

References: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079400/arrayadapter-in-android-to-create-simple-listview) or [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Comment: Could you explain this a little more? Should I have a separate file that contains the 'list items' to call from? Also, what does the second entry of 'R.layout....' represent?

Comment: updated my answer : `activity_main` is the layout of the activity containing the listview, `item` is the layout of the cell's content, `textView` is the `TextView` that will be used to display each entry of your `fulldruglist`, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079400/arrayadapter-in-android-to-create-simple-listview) or [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)