# I want to create and populate a listview with items from an arraylist

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have created this arraylist and with a switch case i am getting the values of the "delhi" arraylist. What i want to do is to create a Listview that will be populated with the items of the arraylist after a button is pressed. I was able to make the items appear on a textview but i cannot do it in a listview

```
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View 
            selectedItemView, int myPosition, long myID) {
            ArrayList<String> delhi = new ArrayList<String>();

            delhi.add("Virgin Atlantic – London Heathrow");
            delhi.add("British Airways – London Heathrow");

            String country = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            switch (country){
                case "Delhi":
                    record = delhi.get(0);
                    //record1 = delhi.get(1);

                    break;
                case "Hongkong":
                    //do something
                    break;
                // etc,etc,etc
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }


    });
```

Comment: Have at look at this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079400/arrayadapter-in-android-to-create-simple-listview

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the ArrayAdapter for the listview like the way of [Using lists in Android wth ListView](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) but I recommend to you to use RecyclerView for achieve the goal that you want [Simple Android recycler view example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584424/simple-android-recyclerview-example)

Answer (score 0):

You need an `ArrayAdapter` which will adapt your `ArrayList`.
Let me give you an example.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView mListView;

public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
     setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

     mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mListView);

     // Your array list.
        ArrayList<String> delhi = new ArrayList<String>();
        delhi.add("Virgin Atlantic – London Heathrow");
        delhi.add("British Airways – London Heathrow");

     // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a 
     // 1st parameter, the type of list view as a 2nd parametr and your 
     // array as a 3rd parameter. android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 
     // consists of a layout with TextViews.
     ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
             this, 
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
             delhi );
     // Setting up your Adapter.
     mListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter); 
  }
}
```

Putting this in an OnClickListener will initiate it on a button press.